# Define a first-order function that combines other first-order functions

Tags: scala

I have this class `MyClass`:

```
abstract class MyClass { def myMethod: A => B }

object MyClass { 
  def apply(dep: A => B)(f: B => B) = new MyClass{ def myMethod = ????? }
}
```

Inside the `apply` method , I'd like to define `myMethod` that combines `f` and `dep` functions like `f(dep)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the following definition for myMethod:

```
def myMethod = dep andThen f
```

or, alternatively (but equivalently):

```
def myMethod = f compose dep
```